# Why is there a big voltage drop across my capacitance multiplier?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, power-filtering

I'm following [this application note](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-176.html) to implement a low noise 48V DCDC boost converter for a microphone phantom power circuit. My boost converter works fine, but I'm having trouble with the capacitance multiplier.

Here's my schematic. You can see it more-or-less follows Figure 2 in that app note.
[image]

I've simulated it in LTSpice, and it works nicely. I used models of the LT8362 and the 2SD1782K. I derated the capacitors for their 48V bias. Once the switcher has finished turning on, there's 47.4V at LT_VOUT. The output of the capacitance multiplier (the +48V rail) is around 46.7V (0.7V dropped across Q26). This is with a simulated load of 10mA. I've also simulated a 100mA transient. That causes a dip to 46.3V on the output and a peak power dissipation in Q26 of around 100mW. These output voltages are fine - the specification calls for 48V +/- 4V with a maximum load current of 10mA. Most importantly, the capacitance multiplier circuit does a good job of attenuating the noise from the switcher.

In reality, however, it behaves totally differently:

With no load, the output of the capacitance multiplier (the +48V node) is in perfect agreement with the simulation. However, with even a light load of a few mA, the output voltage rapidly drops off. Even the input impedance of a multimeter is enough to cause the output to dip a little. Here I have plotted output voltage at different load currents. Around 10mA the output falls off completely.
[image]

I've also noticed that there are a few volts between the the emitter and base, whereas in the simulation these nodes are both equal. I'm also using a smaller transistor than the author of the appnote, but I believe its power dissipation and voltage ratings should be within spec.

Do you have any idea what might be going on?

Thanks.

Comment: If you remove (or avoid) the multiplier circuit, do you see the droop? If so, it's the regulator circuit prior to what you are showing us. Have you done that test? (I can't tell from what I read in your question. Perhaps I missed something you said there?)

Comment: The transistor pinout may be different than expected. If the base-emitter voltage is higher than 0.7V then it is either damaged or installed incorrectly, This isvery likely a wiring problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the output of the capacitance multiplier (the +48V node) is in perfect agreement with the simulation

> Why is there a big voltage drop across my capacitance multiplier?

Is there? Have you measured the input-to-output drop, or just the output relative to ground? The multiplier is hard to get wrong, so assuming you put it together right, it should work fine. **Make sure you actually measure the drop across the multiplier, not just its absolute output voltage**.

If the transistor is not damaged and not installed incorrectly, the base-to-emitter voltage won't be higher than about 0.7V, i.e. the base can be higher than emitter by no more than 0.7V.

If that's not the case, then the transistor is not installed correctly or is damaged.

There will always be about 1V drop from collector to emitter with the circuit as show under load.

I'd first verify that the collector (LT_VOUT) is indeed at 48V. If LT_VOUT is drooping, then the transistor can't help with that.

My bet is that either:

1. The transistor is installed incorrectly (wrong pinout etc, wrong part, broken part),
2. The boost converter's output is sagging under load.

It's most likely that (2) is the case. You'll need to post the entire circuit *as you implemented it* (not an app note!), and also detailed pictures of how you assembled it.

And finally, if you didn't buy the parts from DigiKey, Mouser, or a similar reputable dealer, it's likely you got fakes for something.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply. There definitely is a substantial drop across the capacitance multiplier. Measuring LT_VOUT to "+48V" (i.e. probing with a multimeter between testpoints T6 and T5) I get approx 12V drop with Iout = 3mA. LT_VOUT is dead flat at 47.4 +/- 0.1V across the range of Iout from 0 to 20mA. And yes - genuine parts from Mouser.

Comment: Thanks - bet 1 was correct - the transistor pinout was wrong. For some insane reason Rohm failed to follow the IPC standard and numbered their pins *clockwise" from pin 1! So when I hooked up 1,2,3, to E,C,B or whatever, the definition of 1,2,3 were incorrect for the SC-59 footprint in my EDA tool. I've flipped the part upside down and now the circuit works perfectly.